# Cómo mostrar un ProgressBar desde otra activity

Tags: android, progressbar, progressdialog

Mi pregunta se enfoca en crear un ProgressBar ya que no se puede crear un ProgressDialog porque fue eliminado del android, por eso estoy tratando de crear un ProgressBar que sea como un ProgressDialog en una nueva ventana.

He estado buscando en esta página acerca del ProgressBar y lo que encontré es que lo ponen dentro del layout del Main Activity junto con los botones, etc.
Lo que yo quisiera saber es cuando en una Primera activity descargo una imagen se muestre un layout nuevo con solo el ProgressBar y luego que termine de cargarse vuelva al layout donde estaban los botones. Así como un ProgrressDialog.

Alguna ayuda por favor.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo en mi app un ProgresBar, espero y te sirva:

ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
    private  void  ShowProgressBar ()  {
        progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog ( getContext ());
        progressDialog . setProgressStyle ( ProgressDialog . STYLE_SPINNER );
        progressDialog . setCancelable ( false );
        progressDialog . setTitle ( "Por favor, espere..." );
        progressDialog . setMessage ( "Preparando para acceder Android-SIE..." );
        progressDialog . show ();
    }

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

- Para activarlo desde otro lado: ShowProgressBar () ;
- Para desactivarlo: progressDialog.dismiss ();

  ---

Y asi es como se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dato:

- (lo demás de la pantalla se oscurece y solo se muestra el progress y cuando acaba el ProgressBar vuelve a su estado normal mostrandose todo lo anterior y desaparece el ProgressBar).
- (tienes que tener cuidado cuando lo activas y desactivas, tiene que ser en el momento justo de tu programación, de otra manera el progress bar nunca acabará de cargar y no volverá a su estado normal).